# Bookdown references // separate bibliography per .Rmd file

Tags: reference, r-markdown, bookdown, bibtex

I am using bookdown for my PhD thesis. Everything looks find and I can render the three different .Rmd files using bookdown, with the exception of the references section. Unfortunately, even though I specified separate libraries for each .Rmd file to consider, all references appear after each .Rmd files in the final PDF-Version. I would like to see a separate reference section after each paper, considering only the references cited in this paper, not all the citations in all the papers.
Could someone help me out here? Thank you.

In my index.Rmd:

```
--- 
title: | 
  | \vspace{5cm} \LARGE Essays on Insurance Economics
  | \vspace{0.5cm} \Large Dissertation
author: | 
  | \vspace{0.4cm}
  | \vspace{0.2cm} XY
  | \vspace{0.2cm} Supervisor: XY
  | \vspace{0.2cm} Co-Supervisor: XY
date: "July 16, 2023"
fontsize: 12pt
bibliography: ["bib/Paper1.bib", "bib/Paper2.bib", "bib/Paper3.bib"]
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output:
bookdown::pdf_book:
  fig_caption: yes
  citation_package: biblatex
  bibliography: ["bib/Paper1.bib", "bib/Paper2.bib", "bib/Paper3.bib"]
  includes:
    in_header: latex/preamble.tex
    before_body: latex/before_body.tex
    after_body: latex/after_body.tex
keep_tex: yes
latex_engine: xelatex
link-citations: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{center}
- \includegraphics[width=3.5in,height=3.5in]{logo.png}\LARGE\\}
- \posttitle{\end{center}}
- \usepackage{placeins}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{chngcntr}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
- \setlength\parindent{14pt}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
```

In Paper1.Rmd yaml:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: "bib/Paper1.bib"
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage{placeins}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{chngcntr}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
- \setlength\parindent{14pt}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{tabulary}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
latex_engine: xelatex
linkcolor: black
urlcolor: black
```

In Paper2.Rmd yaml:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: "bib/Paper2.bib"
fontsize: 12pt
header-includes:
- \usepackage{placeins}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{lscape}
- \usepackage{setspace}
- \usepackage{chngcntr}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{tabulary}
- \usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
- \setlength\parindent{14pt}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
- \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
- \renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[2pt]}
- \renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[2pt]}
latex_engine: xelatex
linkcolor: black
urlcolor: black
```

And the same for paper 3..

When I include a nocite in yaml by mentioning the references that should not appear in a given paper, it does not appear anywhere at all, so this does not work either. I even tried different commands for output(pdfbook or pdfdocument).
`